Confidence interval for a slope in a linear model with an interaction
lm(y ~ x + gender + x*gender)

Suppose the experimental units are 15 males and 17 females. It appears that what R does in response to the command above is that it fits an intercept, and an amount to be added to the intercept for one of the two genders, and a slope by which $x$ is multiplied, and a number to be added to the slope for one of the two genders.
Now suppose the errors are homoskedastic. And $$\widehat\sigma^{\,2} = \frac{\text{sum of squares of residuals}}{\text{error d.f.}}= \frac{\text{s.s.r.}}{15+17-4}.$$
We want a confidence interval for the slope $\beta$ that applies to males. We know that
$$
\widehat\beta \sim\operatorname N\left( \beta, \frac{\sigma^2}{\sum_{i\,\in\,M} (x_i-\overline x)^2} \right)
$$
where $M$ is the set of indices corresponding to male units, and $\overline x$ is the observed mean only for the males.
Hence
$$
\frac{\widehat\beta-\beta}{\sigma\left/ \sqrt{\sum_{i\,\in\,M} (x_i-\overline x)^2} \right.} \sim\operatorname N(0,1).
$$
And so
$$
\frac{\widehat\beta-\beta}{\widehat\sigma\left/ \sqrt{\sum_{i\,\in\,M} (x_i-\overline x)^2} \right.} \sim t_{28}.
$$
Thus the endpoints of the confidence interval should be
$$
\widehat\beta\pm A\cdot \frac{\widehat\sigma}{\sqrt{\sum_{i\,\in\,M} (x_i-\overline x)^2}}
$$
where $A$ is the appropriate quantile of the $t_{28}$ distribution.
My question is whether there is something to be said for using, instead of $\widehat\sigma,$ an estimate of standard deviation based only the male units, thus involving the $t_{13}$ distribution? Are there pros and cons of the two approaches? Presumably with different error variances for males and females, the approach above would have to be considered wrong.
I could try to figure this out intelligently rather than asking here, and probably I will, but asking about it here might also turn up some things of interest.

If you don't believe the usual regression assumption of constant error variance across gender, that would be one fairly solid reason to avoid combining estimates of variance across gender -- but then you would probably not want to estimate the coefficients via ordinary unweighted least squares either
